# In Ad Studio, what happens when a contact is removed from the source data extension for an audience?

Tags: marketing-cloud, audience, ad-studio

I'm trying to understand how syncing of advertising audiences works in Ad Studio. In this situation, there is a single ad audience with a data extension as the source. Here are two scenarios:

**Data Extension Overwrite**

1. Customer ABC is added to the data extension, and therefore the ad audience
2. Ad audience syncs to facebook and google and customer ABC gets matched
3. I perform an overwrite of the data extension and customer ABC is not longer in the ad audience

**Data Extension with Individual Record Retention Period**

1. Customer ABC is added to the data extension, and therefore the ad audience
2. Data Extension has a retention period for individual records set for 10 days
3. 10 days passes and customer ABC is removed from the data extension

**Outcome?**

In both of the above cases, once customer ABC is removed from the data extension, what happens in the detinations (eg: facebook, google, etc)? Does customer ABC *also* get removed from the audiences there?

Comment: Yes, but not from the moment the contact is deleted from the data extension, but actually when the audience is refreshed in ad studio. And audiences can be refreshed daily and not more often than that.

Comment: Thanks Javier. Can I ask how you know this? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get a response from Salesforce via our success manager.

For the first scenario **Data Extension Overwrite** they said:

> if a contact is removed from the source DE we also send a removal to the networks. So in both cases the contact would be removed from the destination.

I got further clarification on this behaviour regarding already matched contacts on the network side and in the case of a DE overwrite would contacts that were already matched remain so, and they said:

> we utilise a match table between previous and current refresh so that we only process the delta, even on an overwrite.

I did not end up asking them about the data retention scenario, so not sure on this one. But my guess is it behaves the same way.

Hope that helps someone!